# isn't iterator an object?

Tags: c++, list, for-loop, iterator

this is my code:

```
for (list<moveStringTree>::iterator tempIterator=moveList.begin();tempIterator!=moveList.end(); ++tempIterator)
{
    moveStringTree *move = tempIterator;
}
```

but it gives me an error. if there is a castingway, I don't like it. it is too time consuming. anyway I want to go throw a list and do something with each object in it. what can I do?
foreach won't help. because only it will give a copy.

Comment: Error 1 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'moveStringTree *'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> isn't iterator an object?

It is. An object in C++ is equivalent to a memory location holding a value – no more, no less. However, I don’t see how this relates to the rest of the question.

> but it gives me an error. if there is a castingway, I don't like it. it is too time consuming.

I have no idea what this means. But just in case you meant copy: no, it’s probably not too time-consuming. But if it is – don’t worry; use a reference.

```
moveStringTree& move = *tempIterator;
```

> foreach won't help. because only it will give a copy.

Nonsense. foreach does the same as manually iterating. So you can also use it with a copy:

```
for (auto& o : moveList) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iterator *as if* it was a pointer, but it isn't actually one. There is a dance that you can do to grab a pointer out of it, though:

```
moveStringTree *move = &*tempIterator;
```

The `*` resolves to a reference to the element that the iterator refers to, and the `&` returns the address of that element. The end result is a pointer.

Of course, you probably shouldn't do that. This:

```
tempIterator->doSomething();
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
moveStringTree *move = & (*tempIterator) ;
```

(the parentheses aren't strictly necessary)

The iterator itself is not a pointer to the object, but overloads * to return a reference to the object it refers to; from it you can get a pointer using the normal &.

Notice that normally you don't need to do this, since the iterator overloads also the -> operator, so you can access the object's members using the usual -> syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can gain a reference from `std::for_each`. `moveStringTree* move = &*tempIterator;` would be correct. However, more directly, you can simply use `tempIterator` as if it was *already* a pointer to the object in question.

```
for(auto it=moveList.begin();it!=moveList.end(); ++it) {
    it->f(); // well formed if moveStringTree::f()
}
```

Comment: there is a problem in this case. it gives me a const movelist